# Is it possible to combine spring statemachine with event sourcing pattern?

Tags: event-sourcing, spring-statemachine

My idea is to keep track of states of a domain object by spring statemachine. i.e. statemachine defines how to transit states of the domain object. When the events are persisted/restored to/from the event store, the state of the domain object can be (re)generated by sending events to the statemachine.

However, it seems that creating a statemachine object is relatively expensive, it's not that performant to create a state-machine object whenever a state transition happened on a domain object. If I only maintain a statemachine object, I would worry about concurrency problems. One approach is to have a 'statemachine-pool', but it gets messy if I have to create statamachines for multiple different domain objects.

So is it a good idea to apply spring statemachine with event sourcing pattern?

Comment: In this age of the IT, with the amount of data and events that we have to process, integrating state machines to event sourcing is really good idea but Spring State Machine is too resource heavy for it I think, a concept like Akka FSM with it lesser resource demands fits better, if you want to see an example please check my blog, https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2022/04/18/a-model-driven-event-sourced-cloud-ready-application-with-akka-finite-state-machine-using-kafka-cassandra-and-elasticsearch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that all the transitions are based on events I would say that it is a pretty good idea, yes.

> [The fundamental idea of Event Sourcing is that of ensuring every change to the state of an application is captured in an event object, and that these event objects are themselves stored in the sequence they were applied for the same lifetime as the application state itself.](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html)

The main point about event sourcing is that you store the events leading to a particular state - instead of just storing the current state - so that you can replay them up to a given point of time.

Thus, using event sourcing has no impact on how you create your state machines.

> However, it seems that creating a state-machine object is relatively expensive, it's not that performant to create a state-machine object whenever a state transition happened on a domain object.

Creating a state-machine every time there is a state transition is not related with event sourcing. Would you do it differently if you were only storing the current state? You'd still need to either create the state-machine from the last stored state - or look it up in a cache or a pool - before you could apply the transition.

The only performance hit derived from using event sourcing would be that of replaying the transitions from the beginning in order to reach the current state. Now, if this is costly [you can use snapshots](http://blog.jonathanoliver.com/event-sourcing-and-snapshots/) to minimize the amount of transitions that must be replayed.

Comment: I've been experimenting with using vectors to model 'current app state' - so far I've found the state machine model greatly complements event sourcing - this article seems to pull all the concepts together: http://blockchain.glorat.net/2015/11/16/6-components-of-any-blockchain-design-solution/